# How to get minion's hostname from master

Tags: docker, docker-compose, salt-stack

I am using salt stack. From the master (node01), I am using `cmd.run` to run docker-compose task on minions (node02).

My docker-compose file needs to know the hostname of minion `node02` but currently since the task is being run from master `node01`, the docker-compose file receives the hostname of the master and not the minion.

`node01` and `node02` are on the same network

Salt command run on `node01`

```
 salt-cp -L node02 docker-compose.yml /my/path
 salt -L node02 cmd.run "docker-compose -f /my/path/docker-compose.yml pull &&
 docker-compose -f /my/path/docker-compose.yml down && 
 docker-compose -f /my/path/docker-compose.yml up -d" --timeout=600
```

In the following example Docker Compose file, I would like to pass the `HOST_NAME` to the command. Right now, I have to create multiple different docker-compose files for each node as passing the hostname isn't working

```
version: "3.3"
# interaction
services:
  consul:
    command: -node=HOST_NAME --join=192.168.0.30 --advertise=192.168.0.30
    image: progrium/consul:latest
    hostname: "consul"
    container_name: consul
    ports:
    - "8300:8300"
    - "8400:8400"
    - "8500:8500"
    - "8600:53/udp"
    - "8301:8301"
    - "8302:8302"
    network_mode: "host"
    restart: always
```

In my current setup, how do I pass the hostname of the minion to docker-compose when running the command from the master?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a recipe it could be achieve easily with some jinja in your docker compose file:

in your docker-compose.yml you will have this:

```yaml
version: "3.3"
# interaction
services:
  consul:
    command: -node={{ pillar['docker_hostname'] }} --join=192.168.0.30 --advertise=192.168.0.30
    image: progrium/consul:latest
    hostname: "consul"
    container_name: consul
    ports:
    - "8300:8300"
    - "8400:8400"
    - "8500:8500"
    - "8600:53/udp"
    - "8301:8301"
    - "8302:8302"
    network_mode: "host"
    restart: always
```

When doing a file.managed from the master to the minion, the jinja part will be replaced.

You will have to put this file in the /srv/salt hierarchy. lets say /srv/salt/files/docker-compose.yml

then in /srv/salt/docker.sls:

```
copy docker-compose:
  file.managed:
    - name: '/my/path/docker-compose.yml'
    - source: salt://files/docker-compose.yml.jinja
    - template: jinja

run docker:
  cmd.run:
    - name: "docker-compose -f /my/path/docker-compose.yml pull && docker-compose -f /my/path/docker-compose.yml down && docker-compose -f /my/path/docker-compose.yml up -d"
```

And after you juste have to use your recipe and to pass as a parameter the hostname (test in my example)

`salt 'node2' state.sls docker pillar='{"docker_hostname": "test"}'`

Comment: sorry a bit new to salt and just know enough to be able to use it. thanks for your answer. can you also add an example of the 'recipe' that you talk about?

Comment: `salt 'node2' state.sls docker pillar='{"docker_hostname": "test"}'` by this it seems like, I would still have to hardcode the hostname of the minion from the master? Is there way for minion to know itself and pass it to docker-compose? This is because each node already has a hostname

Comment: Sorry I though you wanted a dynamic hostname. If you want to reuse the node2 host name just replace `{{ pillar['docker_hostname'] }}` in the docker-compose.yml file with the following: `{{ grains['fqdn'] }}`.
It will use the minion hostname. and then you dont have to specify the pillar on the command line.